# Rendering renders reference video rather than the animation

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, video

I imported a storyboard into blender to animate using it, but now whenever I try to render, it renders the imported storyboard mp4 rather than the actual animation in viewport that I created. How do I fix it and make it so that it renders whats on viewport?
[image: here's an image of what I'm talking about]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to deactivate the *Sequencer* option in the *Output panel > Post Processing*:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!